# Javascript (es6) possible to destructure and return on a single line?

Tags: ecmascript-6, object-destructuring

I'm curious if it's possible to return a destructured object on the same line it was destructured.

Current (working) examples:

*using 2 lines*

```
const itemList = json.map((item) => {
    const { id, title } = item;
    return { id, title };
});
```

*1 line but not destructured*

```
const itemList = json.map((item) => {
    return { id: item.id, title: item.title }; // This also requires repeating the field name twice per instance which feels hacky
});
```

Is it possible to condense the body down to one line ?

*example (doesn't work)*

```
const itemList = json.map((item) => {
    return { id, title } = item;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Destructure the callback parameters, and return an object:

```
const itemList = json.map(({ id, title }) => ({ id, title }))
```

Comment: Only works in this specific situation, with array mapper, but not if you had "just" a function and within it the restructuring part, as seen in OP's first example: `() => { const {a,b} = foo; return {a,b}; }`